# How to update a value on a dictionary list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary list in python with some key, values like this:

```
for i in range(1,11):

users.append([ {"id":i, "role":"receiver", "position":i, "personality": "truthful", "number_of_park_reports": 0, "number_of_availability_reports": 0, "number_of_fake_availability_reports": 0, "num_of_usage":0, "points":0, "n":0, "l":0}])
```

I have a loop in witch after some condition I want to add +1 to `number_of_park_reports`:

```
for lp in range(1000):
prob=random.uniform(0, 1)
print(prob)    
for x in p_spaces:

    if(x[0]['state']=="free/free" ):
        usert=random.choices(users)
    
        if usert[0][0]["role"] == "receiver":
            
            if usert[0][0]["personality"]=="truthful":
            
                        
                if (prob<=0.3):           
                    x[0]["state"]="occ/occ"
                    x[0]["receiver"]=usert[0][0]["id"]
                    usert[0][0]["role"]="receiver"
                    usert[0][0]["number_of_park_reports"]=usert[0][0]["number_of_park_reports"]+1

for user in users:
    print[0]["number_of_park_reports"]
```

At the end of the loop I get the value 1 as number of park reports for every user, but I want to get the total `number_of_park_reports` which every user gets in every loop

Answer (score 1):

The output of the program below depends on three conditions:

1. The length of the list p_spaces
2. The return value of the function random.uniform
3. The return value of the function random.choices

random.choices is called once for every element in p_spaces. The probability of increasing number_of_park_reports for an element in users rises every time random.choice is called.

The number_of_park_reports can only be increased, if random.uniform returns a value below or equal to 0.3. Running the program multiple times shows that in some runs number_of_park_reports is not increased in any element of users.

number_of_park_reports is increased in the list element that is returned by random.choices. If random.choices always returns the same list element, the number_of_park_reports is only increased for that element. This is very unlikely to happen but possible.

I don't see any problem with updating the dictionary value of "number_of_park_reports" in your code.

I ran the following program several times (~30) with different sizes of p_spaces. Getting 1 for the number of park reports for every user never happened. So you probably run different code than me. I suspect that the indentation of our programs differ. Please correct the indentation in your code to facilitate reproducing your output.

```
import random


def update_value():
    p_spaces = []
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        p_spaces.append([{'state': "free/free"}])
    users = []
    for i in range(1, 11):
        users.append([{"id": i, "role": "receiver", "position": i, "personality": "truthful", "number_of_park_reports": 0,
               "number_of_availability_reports": 0, "number_of_fake_availability_reports": 0, "num_of_usage": 0,
               "points": 0, "n": 0, "l": 0}])

    for lp in range(1000):
        prob = random.uniform(0, 1)
    print("prob: " + str(prob))
    for x in p_spaces:

        if x[0]['state'] == "free/free":
            usert = random.choices(users)

            if usert[0][0]["role"] == "receiver":

                if usert[0][0]["personality"] == "truthful":

                    if prob <= 0.3:
                        x[0]["state"] = "occ/occ"
                        x[0]["receiver"] = usert[0][0]["id"]
                        usert[0][0]["role"] = "receiver"
                        usert[0][0]["number_of_park_reports"] = usert[0][0]["number_of_park_reports"] + 1

    for user in users:
        print("number_of_park_reports: " + str(user[0]["number_of_park_reports"]))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_value()
```

I recommend using a debugger to understand your code better. You can use https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#start-debugger-session for example.

Best,
Osvald

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to know how to update a value in a dictionary.
This is easily done.

First you have a dictionary as such: `my_dict = {"number_of_park_reports": 0}`

To update `number_of_park_reports` you assign the new value to a variable like this `update_my_dict = {"number_of_park_reports": my_dict.get("number_of_park_reports") + 1}`.
This sets your variable `update_my_dict` to the new value, by getting the old one and adding `1` to it.

Then to actually update `number_of_park_report` you use the dictionary function `update()`, like this `my_dict.update(update_my_dict)`.

This makes `"number_of_park_report": 1` when you print `my_dict`.

Hope that helps you out!

Comment: This is a very strange, clumsy and inefficient way to do `my_dict['number_of_park_reports'] += 1`.....

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Didn't really think of that way, I just posted what I knew. You do have a good point, it is better, so I will try to keep it in mind :)